# NLP, ignoring irrelevant words

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, extract, information-extraction

I developed a simple extractor of passport number from words (for example, input - 'one hundred thirty five thirty five zero zero gets output - 1353500)

but how can I filter out unrelevant words like 'ok', 'mhm' and so on?

for example human can say 'ok it is 1353500' and bot will extract some meaningless numbers from 'ok', 'it', 'is' and it is bad. The question is how to ignore those non-number words?

Comment: i agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are basically stopwords.To remove them,you need to download nltk package which has all the english stopwords

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
w = stopwords.words('english')
#lets say data is a string which has your sentence
for word in w:
   if word in data:
       data.replace(word,'')
```